# Git: getting merge conflict errors, but there's nothing showing on the files to fix

Tags: git, github

I am new to git. I tried pushing some files, but got a merge error on all of them.

I went to check out the files but none of them have the usual `<<<<<HEAD` and `=======` markers indicating where the conflict is. I am unsure what is wrong with these files. In fact, one of them should be brand new.

Would anyone know what could be happening here?

Error:

> CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in filename.css
>   Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

OS is Ubuntu

Git version is 1.7.9.5

Comment: What merge error do you have? What version of Git are you using, on which OS?

Comment: Can you paste the error over here?

Comment: @VonC added above

Comment: A git status should list the files with merge conflict markers